# Logic app Delete document cosmos db gives 404 error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to delete a document from cosmos db using Logic App. The id exists in db, and I have provided the partition key as well. But still I get 404 error.
Can someone assist in adding a delete document function in logic app.
[image: My Logic App Flow]

[image: 404 Error]

But the id exists in db

[image: Document id fetched]
[image: Db]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the partition key value as the actual id instead of "id" which is the partition key path.

Change it to `"fd39d4c4........."` it should work then.